# How to get datetime object from string "DD Month YYY" where month is in full name ex. January

Tags: python, datetime

I've a string, for ex '03 July 2012' and i want a datetime object from this. I'm looking for the most optimum way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Did you read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)?

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('03 July 2012', '%d %B %Y')
datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 3, 0, 0)
```

`%d` stays for day (03), `%B` for full month day (July) and `%Y` for year (2012).

Comment: Thx a lot! I was looking for this only.